# angular component factory, to prevent ngSwitch/if

Tags: angular

I have this ugly piece of code:

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="filter.kind">
    <p-select *ngSwitchCase="filterType.SelectboxFilter"  [settings]="filter" > </p-select>
    <p-autocomplete *ngSwitchCase="filterType.AutocompleteFilter" [settings]="filter" >  </p-autocomplete>
    <p-dropdown  *ngSwitchCase="filterType.DropdownFilter"  [settings]="filter"> </p-dropdown>
    <p-special-autocomplete-filter *ngSwitchCase="filterType.SpecialFilter"  [settings]="filter">  </p-special-autocomplete-filter>
    <p-quantity-filter *ngSwitchCase="filterType.QuantityFilter"  [settings]="filter">  </p-quantity-filter>
</ng-container>
```

I search another way to do it, for example - each filter will hold here components.

it is possible? maybe another way?

Comment: That markup doesn't look that "ugly" to me. You could wrap it in a custom component if you don't want to see the inner workings in the markup of the parent component, or if you want to reuse that code in several places.

Answer (score 0):

you can use instead dynamic-component-loader -"ComponentFactoryResolver"
[angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) - but it is not easy to implement